# How to escape # in ruby_expect?

Tags: ruby, regex, expect

I want to automatize some config sessions with ruby_expect. But there is one problem. I have a session whose prompt is `console#`.

So i have this code block:

```
expect /console#/ do
  send "foobar"
end
```

You see, there is this # in the expect header, and Ruby treats the `/ do` as a comment now, and fails.
I searched in the documentation of Ruby regexps, and it seems that # is a non-control char, and may not be escaped because the parser won't understand this.

How can i realize this code block as a working block, without the # being interpreted as a comment indicator?

Comment: Could you add a link to the documentation, because AFAICS, escaping the `#` is just fine: `rx = /foo\#/; "foo#".match(rx)` works

Comment: Have you tried running this? Are you sure it's not just your syntax highlighting that shows it as a comment?

Comment: @m.buettner: yes `rx = /foo#/; "foo#".match(rx)` also works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
def expect(*patterns, &block)
  p patterns
end

expect /console#/ do
end
```

Output (1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, jruby, rbx):

```
[/console#/]
```

From my editors, only vim gets the syntax highlighting right.

Comment: Yes, it was just the wrong syntax highlighting. Sorry for my dumb question. ;)